# Is it justifiable to tag a moderator in the comment on an asker's question?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I came across this question on AE [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106569/netsh-command-not-found-in-linux-mint-17) which explicitly doesn't involve anything related to Android. Its all about creating a wifi hotspot on a Linux machine where a command didn't work for him. I definitely answered it but later, I realized that the question probably should be at the SuperUser website. But on the other hand, out of all the flags I've raised since joining, I'll touch the ceiling of 25% declined flags soon if two or three gets added into my flags declined history, not to mention that would cause a temporary ban. Note that nobody commented on the question or the answer other than me.

So, it all comes to this. Is it justified to tag a moderator in a comment to migrate this question (I'm afraid of getting a declined flag)? Or should I just wait and let somebody somehow notice that the question should probably be migrated?

Note: It is of course obvious but I must mention that the meaning of Tag is about notifying someone using @*user_name*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), I don't see any way to tag the moderator, unless they closed the question.

Generally, it'd be preferable if you put a comment telling that the question *might* be off-topic and should be better posted on correct site (e.g. Super User). That way, other users can respond to your opinion, by upvoting it (showing an agreement), replying to your comment, or maybe even flagging the question.

If there are no responses (since we can't guarantee that all questions are read by everyone), then try to take this matter on chat. There are regulars who can give you advice about that. In case there's no one at the moment, you can just post a message politely asking if the question is off-topic or not, then wait/leave. You'll get notification when someone replies to your message.

Finally, if there are still no responses, then you have to use your own judgement whether it's appropriate to flag or not. If you're unsure, then just ignore the question and move on.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot subvert the flagging process.  Learn from the feedback.